Why aren't all angles in (n-)spherical coordinates defined relative to the x-axis?
2D polar coordinates are generally measured as $(r, \theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle measured counter-clockwise from the x-axis, and ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$.
Then, spherical coordinates extend this to $(r, \theta, \phi)$ where $\phi$ is the angle measured from the z-axis, and ranges from $0$ to $\pi$.
(I can find lots of examples of texts that swap $\theta$ and $\phi$, but they are all consistent in that one of the angles is measured from the z-axis.)
The hyperspherical coordinates extend this further, such that each additional angle is always measured from the axis of the additional dimension.
My question is : Why are $\theta$ and $\phi$ measured in such totally different ways -- specifically, from different axes? Are there known historical and/or logical reasons?
Because, intuitively, in spherical coordinates, if $\theta$ is the angle from the x-axis towards the y-axis, I would expect $\phi$ to be the angle from the x-axis towards the z-axis instead. But it's not -- it's the opposite!
This seems even weirder to me.
Consider this : let's take the Cartesian vector $x, y, z = [1, 0, 0]$ -- a single unit pointing positively along the x-axis.   Intuitively I'd assume that the spherical coordinates would similarly be $r, \theta, \phi = [1, 0, 0]$. But they're not -- they need to be $r, \theta, \phi = [1, 0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$. Similarly, in a four-dimensional space $x, y, z, w = [1, 0, 0, 0]$ doesn't become $r, \theta, \phi, \psi = [1, 0, 0, 0]$ -- it becomes $[1, 0, \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.
This just seems so unexpected to me that I feel like I'm missing something. Unfortunately, looking all over online I can't seem to find even any acknowledgement of what seems to be such a logical inconsistency, much less any reason behind it. At most, I find suggestions that it arose out of geographical conventions for identifying points on the Earth's surface -- and yet, while longitude corresponds perfectly to $\theta$ ($\pm180°$, spanning 360°), latitude is measured from the equator where it is 0, and extends to $\pm90°$. So $\phi$ isn't even analogous to how latitude is defined -- it's as if we decided that latitude ought to be measured from the North Pole, instead of from the equator.
My question is : Is there some logical or historical reason I'm missing why defining $\phi$ (and additional angles in higher dimensions) is relative to each new axis, rather than to the first axis -- the x-axis -- the way $\theta$ is defined?
--
Follow-up: Thank you to Andrew D. Hwang below for such a clear explanation -- I am responding here because my response is too long to fit into a comment. In terms of that explanation, I understand that $e_2$ is defined differently for "presumably historical/cultural reasons". Perhaps a different way of phrasing my question would therefore be: why aren't they all defined that way, so that points that have Cartesian coordinate of 0 in the new dimension also have angular coordinate of 0 rather than of $\frac{\pi}{2}$? In other words, instead of defining $\theta_n+1$ as the angle measured from $e_n+2$, define it as that minus $\frac{\pi}{2}$, and then instead of defining $s_{n+1} := (\sin\theta_{n+1})\, s_{n} + (\cos\theta_{n+1})\, e_{n+2}$, we would swap sin and cos and define $s_{n+1} := (\cos\theta_{n+1})\, s_{n} + (\sin\theta_{n+1})\, e_{n+2}$. It just seems like such a more natural choice that if a point resides fully in $\mathbf{R}^{n+1}$, and we add a new dimension so that it now resides in $\mathbf{R}^{n+2}$ with a Cartesian coordinate of 0 in the new dimension, that we would want to define the spherical coordinate as such that it would have a value of 0, rather than $\frac{\pi}{2}$. And not only that, but positive angles up to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ would correspond to positive Cartesian values, and negative angles down to $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ would correspond to negative Cartesian values. So I'm still wondering if there's a logical reason for the way it's defined -- e.g. it makes certain common equations simpler -- or if the consideration that, when placing an existing point in a higher dimensional space, the most intuitive new spherical coordinate would be 0 rather than $\frac{\pi}{2}$, is considered unimportant. Especially because, when spherical coordinates were established as a convention, a conscious choice must have been made to depart from the way $\theta$ had been defined on a circle.

Note that the rotations in the $xy$-plane leave the $z$-axis fixed. So rotating the $z$-axis independently is a natural choice.

Different coordinate systems serve different purposes. Just as an example, your choice of a $\theta$-coordinate ranging from $0$ to $2\pi$ is rather inappropriate if what you want is a coordinate system near a point on the positive $x$-axis. For that purpose, a coordinate system measured clockwise from either the positive $y$-axis, or the negative $x$-axis, or the negative $y$-axis, would be much preferable.

Measuring latitude from the north pole vs the equator is just adding (or subtracting) 90 degrees.  Essentially, $\phi$ is latitude and $\theta$ is longitude.

The angle measured fro the $z$ axis can be called the colatitude.

The question you have to answer when you add the $z$ axis to your Cartesian coordinate system is how to measure an angle to an arbitrary point in space that is not on the $x,y$ plane (or either of the other coordinate planes). There are multiple ways to do this and the conventional coordinates use two different ways for $\theta$ and for $\phi$. Why don’t you try making your own definition of spherical coordinates and see how well it works when you write the equations to convert to and from Cartesian coordinates?

$\newcommand{\Vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$tl; dr: Spherical coordinates have a natural recursive structure, whose angle coordinates are shown, and whose "radius" coordinate measures distance from the origin at the center of the unit sphere.

In more detail, suppose $n$ is a non-negative integer and $s_{n} = s_{n}(\theta_{1}, \dots, \theta_{n})$ denotes a "spherical coordinate system" on the unit $n$-sphere $S^{n} \subset \Reals^{n+1}$. We view $\Reals^{n+1}$ as embedded in $\Reals^{n+2}$ by appending a coordinate $0$, i.e., we identify each $\Vec{x}$ in $\Reals^{n+1}$ with $(\Vec{x}, 0)$ in $\Reals^{n+2}$.
Let $e_{n+2} = (\Vec{0}, 1)$ denote the "last" standard coordinate vector in $\Reals^{n+2}$, and let $\theta_{n+1}$ [sic] denote angle measured from $e_{n+2}$, so (for the moment at least) $0 \leq \theta_{n+1} \leq \pi$. Then, suppressing all angles except the last as in the diagram,
$$
s_{n+1} := (\sin\theta_{n+1})\, s_{n} + (\cos\theta_{n+1})\, e_{n+2}
$$
is a "spherical coordinate system" on the unit sphere $S^{n+1}\subset \Reals^{n+2}$.
(Throughout, I use scare quotes around "spherical coordinates" because these are not manifold charts without restriction.)

We can start our recursion with $n = 0$, using $1$ as a "spherical coordinate" on the $0$-sphere in $\Reals^{n+1} = \Reals$, and view polar coordinates (with two small tweaks) in this recursive scheme. This observation addresses the original question.
When $n = 0$, our Cartesian space is a number line; the "unit sphere" is two points, $S^{0} = \{1, -1\}$; and the radial coordinate is a Cartesian number line coordinate. In the notation above, $s_{0}(\theta_{0}) = \cos\theta_{0}$ is a "spherical coordinate system" on $S^{0}$, whose only permissible angles $\theta_{0}$ are integer multiples of $\pi$, conventionally $0$ and $\pi$.
To pass to "spherical coordinates" on the plane, we let $e_{2} = (0, 1)$ denote the "last" standard coordinate vector in the plane $\Reals^{2}$, and let $\theta_{1}$ [sic] denote angle measured from $e_{2}$. Our "spherical coordinate system" is
$$
s_{1} := (\sin\theta_{1})\, s_{0}(\theta_{0}) + (\cos\theta_{1})\, e_{2}
= (\sin\theta_{1} \cos\theta_{0}, \cos\theta_{1}),
$$
with $0 \leq \theta_{1} \leq \pi$ and $\theta_{0} = 0$ or $\pi$. This formula makes analytic and geometric sense for all real $\theta_{1}$, and customarily we don't worry about angle ranges except to ensure the unit sphere (circle) is "parametrized only once."
Earlier, I mentioned two small tweaks. The first is, in the preceding formula, the discrete polar angle $\theta_{0}$ may be eliminated by allowing $\theta_{1}$ to vary over $[-\pi, \pi]$ (thanks to the sign of the sine), or over $[0, 2\pi]$ (thanks to periodicity), or over all reals (periodicity again).
The second tweak is, the "distinguished axis" is $e_{2}$. For presumably historical/cultural reasons of Cartesian plane coordinates, the right-pointing horizontal axis is preferable to the upward-pointing vertical axis. Consequently, we swap our coordinates, settling on the (special-case) formula
$$
s_{1}(\theta_{1}) = (\cos\theta_{1}, \sin\theta_{1})
$$
for all real $\theta_{1}$. (Naturally, we don't need the subscript either, and in practice write $\theta$ rather than $\theta_{1}$.)
At risk of carrying the story past its punch line, we pass to "spherical coordinates" in Cartesian three-space by writing
\begin{align*}
s_{2}(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2})
  &= (\cos\theta_{2})\, e_{3} + (\sin\theta_{2})\, s_{1}(\theta_{1}) \\
  &= (0, 0, \cos\theta_{2}) + (\cos\theta_{1} \sin\theta_{2}, \sin\theta_{1} \sin\theta_{2}, 0) \\
  &= (\cos\theta_{1} \sin\theta_{2}, \sin\theta_{1} \sin\theta_{2}, \cos\theta_{2}).
\end{align*}
Conventionally, some of us write $\theta := \theta_{1}$ and $\phi := \theta_{2}$, and spherical coordinates become
$$
s_{2}(\theta, \phi) = (\cos\theta \sin\phi, \sin\theta \sin\phi, \cos\phi).
$$

Thank you so much for your extremely clear explanation. I feel like it still leaves me with a major question though, which doesn't fit here in a comment, so I have appended my question with a response in the context of the equations you have provided. I hope you can take a look? Thank you.

You're welcome! <> For what it's worth, there are multiple common conventions "in the wild": The use of latitude (elevation from the equator) or of colatitude (angle from the north pole), and the use of $\theta$ to denote longitude or (co)latitude. The respective formulas are essentially equivalent (but do require fiddly attention to signs where orientation matters); what gets used in a particular field presumably depends on convenience and cultural habit.

SUMMARY :
All angles have to be measured (reckoned) with the new Dimension (new Axis)
Only $2D$ is a Special Case where it is immaterial whether we choose x-Axis or y-Axis
Discussion :
Consider $1D$ , where we measure Distance along x-Axis from Origin $O$. We arbitrarily choose right side to indicate Positive numbers & left side to indicate Negative numbers.

Essentially , there is no angle here.
When we embed this is $2D$ , naturally we make the Perpendicular line & name it y-Axis.
Polar Coordinates (2-Spherical Co-ordinates ??) use the angle $\theta$.
The Natural way would be to measure it from the new Axis towards the x-Axis , though the early historical way (used before Spherical Co-ordinates) was what we commonly use.
Essentially , the historical way works because we have only choice for the Plane along which to measure (reckon) the angle , giving us 2 Starting Axes.

The 2 ways shown here are "Complimentary" : knowing one is knowing the other , because the total is $90^\circ$ Constant.
When we embed that in $3D$ , we can not just use x-Axis to measure the angle (towards where ??)
Say we want to measure $30^\circ$ , there will be a Cone around the x-Axis , without referring to z-Axis , like shown in this $3D$ Unit Sphere :

There is no marking for the target Direction (z-Axis) , hence we have to make complicated rules , maybe like "take the xy-Plane & make a Perpendicular & ETC".
That will become more complex/complicated in higher Dimensions.
Instead the "Better Approach" (what-ever that means) is to say that when the new Dimension is added , we get one more Perpendicular at $O$. We always measure from that Axis , though it might go towards x-Axis or y-Axis or what-ever.
It looks like this , in a side view :

In top view , it looks like this , where I am showing the $30^\circ$ Cone (Circle Projection onto the xy-Plane)

We still do not know the End towards which we want to measure , which could be x-Axis or y-Axis or what-ever. That will not matter : We have the Unique Point at Distance $1$ at given $\theta$ & given $\phi$
Likewise , when we embed that in $4D$ , we can not use x-Axis because we have infinite Directional Choices for measuring the angle.
When we use w-Axis (the new Perpendicular) , we can make the new angle there & get the Unique Point at Distance $1$ at given $\theta$ & given $\phi$
In All Cases , when we have the new Perpendicular & we measure from Axis towards Plane (Hyper Plane) we might consider reversing the measurement from Plane (Hyper Plane) towards Axis , due to the nature of the Model where that is more appropriate or more useful. Ocean Navigation , Cartography & GPS are the Examples here.
We still can not measure it from x-Axis to new Perpendicular , which has infinite choices & is ambiguous & hence cumbersome to disambiguate.
Specifically , in $3D$ , when we measure $\theta$ & $\phi$ along x-Axis , we will get 2 Concentric Circles.
ADDENDUM :
OP : This just seems so unexpected to me that I feel like I'm missing something.
What you are missing is that on the $3D$ Earth , the angle is measured from North Pole towards Equator , not towards some x-Axis going though some City from the Center.
When we say Equator , we mean Equatorial Plane , which is Unique.
We can not measure from North Pole towards some arbitrary x-Axis , which would not work.
We can not measure from arbitrary x-Axis (towards what ??) , which would be ambiguous.
In $2D$ , which is a Special Case , these two ways work out , though that is the Exception.

Thank you for your explanation! I realize that I should have been more precise in my question -- that indeed "from the x-axis" is correct if we are considering a point whose Cartesian coordinate is nonzero in only one dimension. I have appended my question so that it is now mathematically precise -- it essentially boils down to, why not define each new angle in the range $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ rather than in the range $[0,\pi]$? Then 2D would not be a special case, and new spherical coordinates would be 0 when the new Cartesian coordinate was 0, which seems much more elegant.

(1) I think I answered the title "Why aren't all angles in (n-)spherical coordinates defined relative to the x-axis?" that we can not use x-Axis [ except $2D$ ] , @crazygringo , we have to always use the new Perpendicular. (2) There is no worry about using some other "Interval" : We could even use $[0,1]$ , $[-1,+1]$ , $[A,B]$ , though we have to handle the trigonometric calculations suitably.
